# Could a single impulse be classified as a sound wave?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

If not, how many counts(cycles) of impulses are needed before we can call it as sound(without 20-20000Hz limit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although sound is something we originally defined as a wave that could be sensed by some biological mechanism in some organisms, it has found a more specific meaning in physics as a wave that propagates energy through some type of media by compressing and rarifying the density of that media as it propagates. So sound then is most often thought about as a traveling, longitudinal compression wave that behaves in a cyclic manner.

But the definition does not need to restrict itself to cyclic waves. And so a specific frequency range cannot really be used to define what is and what is not a *sound* wave. Short event disturbances in a medium can also propagate a solitary wave or [soliton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) that can be detected by instrumentation or *heard* by organisms, if the mechanisms are capable of absorbing the energy of the soliton wave and generating a signal to the instrument or stimulating the brain of the organism. But unlike a cyclic sound wave, the instrument or brain cannot count or 'integrate' over a number of wave cycles to discern the presence of any frequency content. And in this case the solitary wave is rather sensed as an impulse - which the organism may refer to as a 'click' or 'pop'.

Answer (score 1):

In case of light, i know for sure that the optic nerve needs only one foton to excite one optic cell.
As for sounds, from [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/28163/whats-the-shortest-sound-perceptible-to-the-human-ear) you have

"A 1,000-Hz tone sounds like 1,000 Hz in a 1-second tone burst, but an extremely short burst > sounds like a click. The duration of such a burst also influences the perceived loudness. Short bursts do not sound as loud as longer ones... A pulse 3 milliseconds long must have a > level about 15dB higher to sound as loud as a 0.5-second (500 millisecond) pulse. Tones and > random noise follow roughly the same relationship in loudness vs. pulse length.

The 100-msec region is significant... Only when the tones or noise bursts are shorter than this amount must the sound-pressure level be increased to produce a loudness equal to that of long pulses or steady tones or noise. This 100 msec appears to be the integrating time or the time constant of the human ear. (Everest 2001, 60-61)"